# Setting a User when calling cloud code from cURL (for testing)

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to call a cloud function using cURL (or from Postman) for testing. The problem is, I need to somehow set a "current user" so I can use `request.user`.
I've tried everything I can think of - setting it in the body of the request, using `useMasterKey`, fetching a user from an `objectId` and assigning it within the cloud code function etc. I've even tried making the request through a proxy to try see how it's done, so I could replicate it... I've got nothing.

Simply trying to save a new object to a class `Orders` with a `user` object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have a request.user in present in your cloud code, you will need to pass in a session token.

First query the session class.

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  https://YOUR.PARSE-SERVER.HERE/parse/sessions
```

Then pick any user session token and add that to the header of your orginal request.

The header should be in this format

"X-Parse-Session-Token: your_session_token"

And it will work.